# accessing internal storage of android device without powering on device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-storage, ram, micromax-a110

i own a canvas micromax. while experimenting with the motherboard i accidentally screwed with the power button. my device is as such fine but the power button has stopped functioning due to which i cant switch on my phone. i will get the thing repaired but meanwhile wish to access the internal storage which has important data. 
my query is how to retrieve internal storage data without actually powering on the mobile. Can i opt for PC suite.? please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need specialist tools to connect directly to the flash memory, I doubt it's practical to do so and you're more than likely to cause some more irreversible damage to your device. See [How can I physically remove the internal memory device from my Samsung Galaxy S2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63170/how-can-i-physically-remove-the-internal-memory-device-from-my-samsung-galaxy-s2) or [iFixIt's guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/108121/How+to+recover+(internal+data+from)+completely+dead-powerless+phone)

On the other hand, you might have luck trying to power on your device by plugging it to a USB port, then using adb from there.